# Shopify Billing API - giving a user a free month

Tags: api, shopify

I have an App in the Shopify App store that uses a recurring application charge. No problems there.

Sometimes, one of my users will make a suggestion to improve the app. I would like to reward them with a free month of using the app without being charged.

Based on the Shopify API, The only thing I can think of is to cancel the current recurring application charge, create a new charge for $0, then a month later cancel that charge and create new one for the original price. This is far from ideal. I believe that the user would need to accept every new charge that is created.

Is there a better way? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2017 there is now an API for granting credits to merchants using your app: 
https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/using-the-shopify-api-to-credit-merchants-for-app-charges
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/applicationcredit

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that that sounds pretty far from ideal.

If you create a new recurring app charge with a 30 day trial period, Shopify will change the customer over to this new charge while respecting the trial period. The customer will still see a prorated charge for the partial payment cycle before you “upgraded their plan” after the trial is up, but this will effectively do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Edward. The user will still have to verify the charge by going into the app. I'm hoping to find a more seamless approach. At this point, I'm not sure if one exists.

Comment: I think Edward has the right idea here. I think that's as far as you can go with using the Shopify billing API. This is why my last company eventually moved to using Stripe for billing Shopify customers, which gives you more flexibility. Ultimately though, I think it's better to have Shopify handle it for you for ease of use.